# Functional Analysis - Integral Question

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Suppose $a,b > 0$ and $p, q > 1$, and $\frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{q} = 1$. Show that $ab \le \frac{a^p}{p}+ \frac{b^q}{q}$ by letting $s = (ab)^{1/2}$. Thus, there is a $t$ such that $a = ts$ and $b = t^{-1}s$, and finding the minimum over all positive $t$. When does the equality hold?

Next, show that if $\int^b_a{|f(t)|^pdt} = \int^b_a{|g(t)|^qdt}=1$ then $\int{|f(t)g(t)|dt} \le 1$

---

I don't even know where to begin with this question. I've tried writing out the different equations given and made some substitutions but that resulted in complicated expressions that didn't seem to lead anywhere. Any help, even just pointing me in the right direction would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With $a = ts$ and $b=t^{-1}s$, we have, let
$$f(t) = \frac{a^p}{p}+\frac{b^q}{q} = \frac{s^pt^p}{p} + \frac{s^q}{t^q q}$$
Optimizing over $t$, we have
$$ f'(t) = s^p t^{p-1} - s^qt^{-q-1}$$
and thus (note that $p+q = pq$)
\begin{align}
f'(t) = 0 &\qquad\Longleftrightarrow\qquad s^p t^{p-1} = \frac{s^q}{t^{q+1}}\\
   &\qquad\Longleftrightarrow\qquad t^{p+q}=s^{q-p}\\
   &\qquad\Longleftrightarrow\qquad t = s^{\frac{q-p}{q+p}} = s^{\frac{q-p}{pq}} = s^{\frac{1}{p} - \frac{1}{q}}.
\end{align}
With this value, $a = s^{\frac{1}{p} - \frac{1}{q} + 1} = s^{\frac{2}{p}}$ and $b = s^{\frac{2}{q}}$, and the minimum value of $f$ is
$$\frac{a^p}{p}+\frac{b^q}{q} = f(t)\geq f\left(s^{\frac{1}{p} - \frac{1}{q}}\right) = \frac{s^2}{p}+\frac{s^2}{q} = s^2 = ab$$
The second inequality follows as @Klaus said.

Comment: Thank you, Sean! Could you show the steps for how you went from f'(t)=0 to solving for t? I've been trying to figure out how you solved for t but I'm having difficulty!

Comment: I just added some more explanations.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you absolutely must use the suggested way to solve it, I recommend considering the function $f(a) := \frac{a^p}{p}+\frac{b^q}{q} - ab$ instead, treating $b$ as a constant. Then the standard calculus procedure shows that the minimum of this function is $0$, implying the first inequality. The second inequality is then a direct application with $a = |f(t)|$ and $b =|g(t)|$.